# How Operating System callbacks work

Tags: c++, c, unix, posix

Follow up question to:
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223040/c-timers-in-unix)

As described in the linked question, we have an API that uses an event look that polls select() to handle user defined callbacks.

I have a class using this like such:

```
class example{
 public:
    example(){
        Timer* theTimer1 =  Timer::Event::create(timeInterval,&example::FunctionName);
        Timer* theTimer2 =  Timer::Event::create(timeInterval,&example::FunctionName);
        start();
       cout<<pthread_self()<<endl;
    }
  private:
     void start(){
        while(true){
           if(condition)
              FunctionName();
           sleep(1);
        }
     }
     void FunctionName(){
         cout<<pthread_self()<<endl;
         //Do stuff
     }
};
```

The idea behind this is that you want FunctionName to be called both if the condition is true or when the timer is up.  Not a complex concept.  What I am wondering, is if FunctionName will be called both in the start() function and by the callback at the same time?  This could cause some memory corruption for me, as they access a non-thread safe piece of shared memory.

My testing tells me that they do run in different threads (corruption only when I use the events), even though: `cout<<pthread_self()<<endl;` says they have the same thread id.

Can someone explains to me how these callbacks get forked off?  What order do they get exectued?  What thread do they run in?  I assume they are running in the thread that does the select(), but then when do they get the same thread id?

Comment: should be tagged as C not C++

Comment: @Tom, the code sample is obviously C++...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer would depend on the implementation of Timer, but if you're getting callbacks run from the same thread, it's most likely using [signals](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) or [posix timers](http://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_create). Either way, [select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) isn't involved at all.

With signals and posix timers, there is very little you can do safely from the signal handler. Only certain specific signal safe calls, such as [read()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) and [write()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) (**NOT** fread() and fwrite(), or even new and cout) are allowed to be used. Typically what one will do is write() to a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) or [eventfd](http://linux.die.net/man/2/eventfd), then in another thread, or your main event loop running select(), notice this notification and handle it. This allows you to handle the signal in a safe manner.

Comment: You are right.  Select is only there because the Event api handles select() events as well as Timers.  >.<  This appears to check the event times in a loop!  (seperate thread)

Comment: Incidentally, apis using signals are really rather painful to work with. Encourage whoever made it to run those callbacks as regular functions in a thread so they only have to take locks :)

Comment: For now I've just circumvented this with my own loop for the events.  Obnoxious, I know, but at least I can properly make them thread safe...

Answer (score 1):

Your code as written won't compile, much less run.  Example::FunctionName needs to be static, and needs to take an object reference to be used as a callback function.

If the timers run in separate threads, it's possible for this function to be called by three different threads.